# Google Colab で pip install が使用できない

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pip

google colaboratoryでPythonを使っています。`pip install` などの外部ライブラリから引用するコマンドが使えません。pip自体に「"pip" is not defined」というエラー出るので、pipのバージョンの問題ではないと思います。

Python初心者なので、提示する情報が足りていないかもしれませんが答えていただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

#### エラー

```
File "<ipython-input-1-b0bfe1142762>", line 2
    pip install pycryptodome
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

#### コード

```
pip install pycryptodome
from Crypto.Util import number

def elgamal_gen_key(bits):
    while True:
        q = number.getPrime(bits-1)
        p = 2*q + 1
        if number.isPrime(p):
            break

    while True:
        g = number.getRandomRange(3, p)
        if pow(g, 2, p) == 1:
            continue
        if pow(g, q, p) == 1:
            continue
        break
    x = number.getRandomRange(2, p-1)
    y = pow(g, x, p)
    return (p, g, y), x
def elgamal_encrypt(m, pk):
    p, g, y = pk
    assert(0 <= m < p)
    r = number.getRandomRange(2, p-1)
    c1 = pow(g, r, p)
    c2 = (m * pow(y, r, p)) % p
    return (c1, c2)
def elgamal_decrypt(c, pk, sk):
    p, g, y = pk
    c1, c2 = c
    return (c2 * pow(c1, p - 1 - sk, p)) % p

pk, sk = elgamal_gen_key(bits=20)
print('pk:', pk) 
print('sk:', sk) 
print()

m = 314159 # 平文
print('m:', m)
c = elgamal_encrypt(m, pk) # 暗号化
print('c:', c)
d = elgamal_decrypt(c, pk, sk) # 復号
print('d:', d)
```

Comment: [Google Colabでpipを使う方法](https://tech-market.org/colab-pip/)

Comment: 具体的なコードとエラーメッセージを載せていただけますか？

Comment: GoogleColaboratoyのセルで「pip」と入力しても質問のように”「"pip" is not defined」というエラー”は表示されませんでした。

Comment: 全角文字で入力しているのかもしれませんね。あるいは`i`ではなくて`l`になっているとか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

原因は`pip install pycryptodome`の行と、それ以後の行を同じセルに入力しているからですね。

`pip install pycryptodome`だけを単独のセルに入力して、`from Crypto.Util import number`以後の内容を次のセルに分けて入力し、順番に実行すれば問題無く動作します。

なお一応、`pip install pycryptodome`の行は、頭に`!`を入れて`!pip install pycryptodome`としておきましょう。